# Log-in to Google Account in Android WebView

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-play-services, accountmanager, google-authentication

I'm integrating Google Drive in my application.

Using the below link I'm able to connect to Google drive and able to download files and able to upload files to Google drive.

https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-android

Below is the code I'm using to upload file to Drive.

Inline image 2

Using the above code I'm able to upload a file to drive and from the line numbers 20 - 23 in the above pic, I'm getting the file meta data such as downloadUrl, alternateUrl and webcontentLink.

Now I'm trying to load a WebView with the AlternateUrl and the page is loading but it is asking for Google credentials again. How to avoid the webview from asking Google Credential. Programmatically, how to login to Google account in webview without explicitly entering Google username and password. I want webview to pick account using either AccountManager or Google Play Service api.

I referred below links, but not able to get it done what I needed.

http://nelenkov.blogspot.in/2012/11/sso-using-account-manager.html

Any help in this regard would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I don't see an attached image..?

Comment: Plz find the below link... https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B72XT5G1XBYzQktKSGRGMXlCbG8/edit?usp=sharing